# Return fault response on failure of assertion in soap ui

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, soap-client

i am working with soap ui and i have a requirement where i am sending a request its been validated and get the response back. Problem is everytime i get the ok response back. For eg i have an assertion like

```
def id =null
assert id!=null : "id is NULL"
```

In the above case i should get back a fault response like

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://cio.att.com/commonheader/v3">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>?</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="?">?</faultstring>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <faultactor>?</faultactor>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <detail>
        <v3:WSException>
          <v3:Message>?</v3:Message>
          <v3:ErrorCode>?</v3:ErrorCode>
        </v3:WSException>
        <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but i always get

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://lsr.att.com/order/service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:OK/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can somebody suggest how can i achieve this?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, however if you expect a `soap:fault` from your server instead of an empty response for a specific request, the problem is in your server not in soapui.

Comment: I am second to @albciff. You should contact the service provider or with your team if it is internal to your organization. Nothing you can do in client side for a problem on the server side.

Comment: You sem to be very confused about how this works. Have a read through the documentation: https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/functional-testing.html